# how i match date or time every time for show alert calender event?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to build a application. In this application, we can save event in device calendar. (it's done) (ANDROID)
But,

> how i match time always. when current time and eventBegins time match
>   than show notification.

NOte: (it match always after close application also "In Android").

Comment: did you mean you want to display alert at the time of event ?

Comment: alert or any notification. when time is match

Comment: Are you using device's default calender and set events into it ?

Comment: yes, i add event using device's default calendar ..

Comment: then in iphone it will automatically give you alert based on saved event's date n time...

Comment: Yes, I know, but not in Android. how i do in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Android**

To set remainder you have have to create event like :

```
// Create the event
var eventBegins = new Date(2010, 11, 26, 12, 0, 0);
var eventEnds = new Date(2010, 11, 26, 14, 0, 0);
var details = {
    title: 'Do some stuff',
    description: "I'm going to do some stuff at this time.",
    begin: eventBegins,
    end: eventEnds
};

var event = calendar.createEvent(details);

// Now add a reminder via alert for 10 minutes before the event.
var reminderDetails = {
    minutes: 10,
    method: Ti.Android.Calendar.METHOD_ALERT
};
event.createReminder(reminderDetails);
```

(Note: Not fully tested code just for an idea) try it..